# Trying to send form information to a database PHP / MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

Hi I do not understand why this code is not inserting the data from the html text feilds into my actually database. I am trying to sample it using just First_Name to start with.

Anyways HTML code is as followed :

```
<form action="Proform.php" name="Myform" method="post">

        <input type ="hidden" value="1" name="check_submit" />
        Please Enter First Name: <input type ="text" name="First_Name" /> <br />
        Please Enter Second Name: <input type ="text" name="Second_Name" /><br />
        Please Enter Email Address: <input type ="text" name="Email_Address" /><br />
        Please Enter A Password: <input type="password" name="Password" /><br />
        <input type ="submit" name"Submit" /><br />

    </form>
```

And php and MYSQL is as followed :

```
 <?php

    $dbname='ecig';
    $dbhost='localhost';
    $dbpass='password';
    $dbuser='eciguser';



    $dbhandle = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass)
      or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
    echo "Connected to MySQL<br>";


    $selected = mysql_select_db("ecig",$dbhandle)
      or die("Could not select examples");



    $res=mysql_query("INSERT INTO Persons (First_Name, Second_Name) VALUES ('$_POST[First_Name]')");

    if (array_key_exists ('check_submit', $_POST )) 

    echo "Your Name is : {$_POST['First_Name']}<br />";
    echo "Your Second Name is : {$_POST['Second_Name']}<br />";
    echo "Your Email Address is : {$_POST['Email_Address']}<br />";
    echo "Your Password Is : {$_POST['Password']}<br />";

    ?>
```

It must have something to do with this line of code but I cannot spot it.. Can any of you spot what is going wrong?

```
$res=mysql_query("INSERT INTO Persons (First_Name, Second_Name) VALUES ('$_POST[First_Name]')");
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks .

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). See the [red box](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you pick PDO [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$res=mysql_query("INSERT INTO Persons (First_Name, Second_Name) VALUES ('$_POST[First_Name]')");
```

I can see a couple things wrong with this query. First you say you only want to start with the first name, so you need only insert into the first name column only:

```
Persons (First_Name  ) VALUES
                    ^
```

Then, looking, you want to make sure you are getting your variable to fill in the string. You want to use:

```
('{$_POST['First_Name']}')
  ^       ^          ^ ^
```

Also consider error testing since this is more than likely a MySQL Syntax error. You can add

```
if (!$res) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

**NOTICE:** Do not use MySQL_* as it has been deprecated as of PHP 5.5. Use MySQLi_* or PDO. Also, you should use prepared statements and SQL escapes. You are open for injection.

Comment: Helped allot got the database collecting data now. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You're telling the query you are going to supply first_name and last_name but you're only providing the first_name:

```
$res = mysql_query("INSERT INTO Persons (First_Name, Second_Name) VALUES ('$_POST[First_Name]')");
```

Try:

```
$res = mysql_query("INSERT INTO Persons (First_Name, Second_Name) VALUES ('$_POST[First_Name]', '$_POST[Lirst_Name]')");
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Insert Query is incorrect. You must provide the same number of values as columns.

```
$res=mysql_query("INSERT INTO Persons (First_Name, Second_Name) VALUES ('$_POST[First_Name]')");
```

Should be:

```
$res=mysql_query("INSERT INTO Persons (First_Name, Second_Name) VALUES ('$_POST[First_Name]', '$_POST[Last_Name]')");
```

Answer (score 1):

You are only passing one value in

$res=mysql_query("INSERT INTO Persons (First_Name, Second_Name) VALUES ('$_POST[First_Name]')");

, and in your insert statement you are inserting 2 values,  First Name and second name.

Try this:

`$res=mysql_query("INSERT INTO Persons (First_Name, Second_Name) VALUES ('$_POST[First_Name]', '$_POST[Second_Name]')");`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

add this to the php code:

```
$firstname             =    $_POST['First_Name'];
$secondname        =    $_POST['Second_Name'];
```

and then change the query to:

```
    $res=mysql_query("INSERT INTO Persons (First_Name, Second_Name) VALUES ('".$firstname."', '".$lastname."')");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$res=mysql_query("INSERT INTO Persons (First_Name, Second_Name) VALUES ('$_POST[First_Name]', '$_POST[Second_Name]')");
```